# Incorrect Login Notification Missing using user-login.tpl.php

Tags: 7, users

I've customized my logged in user page using a template file in D7 (user-login.tpl.php).

Problem I can't figure out is that if they type in the wrong login/pass, it just reloads the page and there is no message stating "Sorry, unrecognized username or password". This can be confusing for them. How can I get it to show up?

Here is my code for my template file:

```
<?php
print drupal_render($form['name']);
print drupal_render($form['pass']);
print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
print drupal_render($form['actions']);
?>
```

Comment: You should never, ever, use `drupal_get_form` in tpl files. Can't find source now, but I'm pretty sure I was told that by a guy who *wrote* `drupal_get_form` function. What you are doing is putting in view layer something that is expected to happen only in controller layer. And Form API is not designed for that.

Comment: Thanks. My PHP skills lets just say are basic at best. So hoping someone could give some example suggestions.

Comment: Drupal is not *exactly* MVC, but if in doubt treat modules as models and controlers, and themes (including module-provided tpl files) as views. [Wikipedia MVC description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is not that bad, if you remember Drupal already blurs one border :)

Comment: I did a bit more digging and replaced the drupal_get_form that you were cautioning about. Any ideas why I still don't get the notifications?

Comment: The steps are: create/get form in module, pass it for templating. Can't see you doing that. It's about midnight for me, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks. There has to be an easier way. Hundreds/Thousands of sites customize their log-in pages and don't have this issue.

Comment: For me '/user' always seemed to do exactly what you are trying, out of the box. All I needed was not to break defaults.

Comment: drupal_render($form) won't do?

Comment: looking at the output, is the form itself being built? if you are rendering individual elements, the actual form itself might not be rendering, causing the problem - if that's the case, you can customise the form elements in a module or template.php so that it renders the way you want using $form